# How do I make a rotating point on an elliptical path?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, simulation

Using Desmos graphing calculator, I am trying to create an accurate 2D model of our solar system. Currently, I have created all of the planets using completely circular orbits, which can then be easily animated using a slider and a bit of trigonometry. For instance the graph for Neptune

[image: here]

However, now I am adding in some other objects, including Pluto, Ceres and comets, I can no longer ignore the elliptical properties of their orbits. For Pluto I have specified its orbital path
[image: here]
yet I cannot work out how to animate its movement as I did on equation 84 and 85 on the first image. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I can't read your equations, they're too grainy.

Comment: For the first equation: \left(x-d_{7}\sin\left(s_{7}\right)\right)^{2}+\left(y-d_{7}\cos\left(s_{7}\right)\right)^{2}\le r_{7}^{2}

Comment: Then the ellipse is: \frac{\left(x-1469.56\right)^{2}}{5906.38^{2}}+\frac{\left(y\right)^{2}}{5720.65^{2}}=1

Comment: That didn't turn out right! You forgot the [dollar signs](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).